# No se como limitar el Random en esta funcion

Tags: java, random

Adjunto todo el código con el cual estoy trabajando, el problema es que al digitar el número de pacientes se supone que en el día debería llegar hasta el número o menos, pero en algunas ocasiones este tiende a ser más alto que el valor asignado, no se si esto sea debido a la función random o dependa de otra cosa, por favor ¿alguien sabe por qué?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Fuerza_Bruta {

    
    /*Un hospital abre sus puertas 5 días a la semana "Lunes,Martes,Miércoles,Jueves,Viernes" cuenta con 6 doctores, 
     * los doctores cuentan con "n" cantidad de pacientes con un limite de pacientes de "cantidad Pacientes/doctores". 
     * Calcular cuantos pacientes atendió cada doctor en el trascurso de la semana, que doctor atendió mas y cual atendió menos?*/
    
    //Dias = Columnas y Doctores = filas
    //5 = Dias y 6 = Doctores
    
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int matriz [][] = new int [6][5]; //5 = Dias/Columnas 6 = Doctores/Filas
    int pacientes;
    static int cantDoc = 6;
    int limitePac = 0;
    int residuo = 0;

    public void DigitarPacientes() {
        
        System.out.println("Digite la cantidad de pacientes");
        pacientes = sc.nextInt();
        
        //System.out.println("La cantidad de pacientes es: " +pacientes);   
            
    }
    
    public void limitePacientes() {
        
        limitePac = pacientes/cantDoc; 
        residuo = pacientes%cantDoc;
        
        System.out.println("La cantidad de pacientes por doctor es de: " + limitePac + "\npacientes no asignados: "+residuo);
    
    }
    
    public void llenar() {
        
        System.out.println("          pacientes"); 
        for (int i=0; i < matriz.length; i++) {

            System.out.print("doctor"); 

            for (int j=0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {
                      
                matriz[i][j] = (int) (Math.random()*limitePac + residuo);
              
                //System.out.println("Matriz ["+i+"]["+j+"]: ");

                System.out.print("["+matriz[i][j]+"]");

            }
              
            System.out.println(""); 
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Fuerza_Bruta p = new Fuerza_Bruta();
        
        p.DigitarPacientes();
        p.limetePacientes();
        p.llenar();
        
    }

}
```

Comment: 'debería llegar hasta el número o menos' -> cual numero debe ser el limito maximo diario? Es limitePac ?

Comment: Ya logre solucionar el error estaba tomando los valores al revés, por ende asignaba un valor aleatorio entre los pacientes y no como tal al limite que debería asignar por doctor, igual muchas gracias <3

Comment: No coloques solucionado al titulo de la pregunta, si la respuesta publicada te ayudo entonces lo correcto sería marcarla como aceptada o calificarla con un +1 o que publiques tu solución

Answer (score 0):

Hola si solo quieres crear un numero aleatorio entre 0 y n, quizas te sirva utilizar la clase **java.util.Random** junto con el metodo **nextInt(int bound)** el cual te regresa un valor aleatorio entre 0 y n-1, donde n es el valor ingresado.

```
Random random = new Random();
int pacientesCreados = random.nextInt(pacientes);
```

Si quisieras asegurar que siempre tengas al menos un paciente como resultado solo le tendrias que sumar 1 siempre al valor que obtienes despues de llamar al metodo.

```
int pacientesCreados = random.nextInt(pacientes) + 1;
```

[Random.nextInt(int bound)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-)